# Disk IO bottleneck on Linux server

Tags: linux, disk, io, ssd, streaming

I've been facing Disk IO bottleneck on one of my streaming server, but couldn't identify the limiting factor. The issue might be on RAID card or in SSD due to which streaming application goes for the disk sleep (uninterruptible) and can't serve properly. Disk utilization is almost always 80%

Here are some details.

Link Speed: 6.0 Gb/s
  Media Type: SSD
  Interface Type: SATA

Hardware used for RAID: **LSI MegaRAID SAS 9266-8i**
 Configured: **Raid 0** on single disk.
 Host Bus Type x8 lane PCI Express 2.0 compliant .

output of a `top` command. It's showing **14.1wa** currently.

[image: output of top command]

Here is another image from `iotop -o` command. Disk Read is **380M/s** on average.

[image: output of iotop -o command]

In Cisco UCS server we can configure single disk as a raid 0 which I've been doing here. My question is If I set up 2 SSD for Raid 0, according to raid calculator I can obtain 2x read and write speed performance which means **1228.8MB/s** practically. Am I right?

Comment: ~500 + overhead on sata (750 max) is not bad, get nvme if you want more speed

Comment: Is that consumer grade hw?

Comment: OK. It might be slightly more obvious that you expect multiples of SATA SSD read performance if you say exactly what the structure of this RAID is. E.g. is it a RAID1 "mirror" with two SSDs?

Comment: And I'm sorry to nag, but e.g. current upstream kernel versions had a massive change in "disk utilization", which makes it a massive under-estimate for single-threaded reads from spinning HDD. It might not even be an issue in this scenario, but can you please edit to mention the kernel version you are using?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro it's cisco ucs c240 m3 server

Comment: @sourcejedi currently I'm using single SSD and it's on raid 0 but planning to use 2 disks and configure it raid 0. In the new setup, Can I expect better performance than before? will there be any limitation on raid card?

Comment: @user1133275 I don't think my organization will go for nvme. But can I obtain around 1000MB/s if I go for 2 disks and configure hardware raid 0?

Comment: How would a RAID with 1 disk work, anyway? I fail to see a point in that. Anyway, if you can get 380 out of one disk, how would two give you a 1000?

Comment: @tink  In cisco UCS we can configure Raid 0 on a single disk too. I guess here performance is improved through controller caching only. But If I set up 2 disks for Raid 0, according to raid calculator I can obtain 2x read and write speed performance which means 1228.8MB/s practically. Am I right?